# How to preserve git modified files in docker dev container

Tags: git, docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am using remote container extension in VSCode to work with my docker containers. While I am able to make a remote connection to my client container for example, the git history is showing most of the files as modified or deleted. How do I go about keeping git in-sync with my local project structure?

My local setup looks as the following,

```
- app
   - client
      - .devcontainer
      - Dockerfile
   - server
      - .devcontainer
      - Dockerfile
   - docker-compose.yml
```

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  server:
    build: ./server
    volumes:
      - ~/.ssh:/root/.ssh
      - ./server/src:/app/src
      - api-modules:/app/node_modules
  client:
    build: ./client
    depends_on:
      - server
    volumes:
      - ~/.ssh:/root/.ssh
      - ./.git:/app/.git
      - web-modules:/app/node_modules
      - ./client/src:/app/src
      - ./client/public:/app/public
volumes:
  api-modules:
  web-modules:
```

Client Dockerfile

```
FROM node:10

COPY . /app/

WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT yarn start;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see, currently...

- ... you copy `/app` into the container (with same path) during **container creation**.
- ... You mount `./.git` as **volume** into `/app/.git`

That means `/app` is at the state your local directory was in when the container was created the last time.
While `/app/.git` is reflecting your current local state (because it's a mounted volume reading from your local `./.git`).
That's why `git` in the container will see working directory differences as its contents are not in the state `git` expects them to be (based on git's history/state stored in `.git`).

Solutions:

Either remove the `/app/.git`-volume from `docker-compose.yml` and re-create the container whenever you changed the code (to update `/app/`).

Or mount `./` as volume to `/app/` in the container (not just the subdir .git), *instead* of copying `/app` in the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

In you docker-compose file you can create and mount the volume client_path to /app

example:

```
  client:
    volumes:
    - <client_path>:/app
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem, here https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/connect-multiple-containers I found out that you have to put a cached binding in your `docker-compose.yml` file, like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  server:
    build: ./server
    volumes:
      - ~/.ssh:/root/.ssh
      - ./server/src:/app/src
      - api-modules:/app/node_modules
      # Mount the root folder that contains .git
      - .:/workspace:cached
  client:
    build: ./client
    depends_on:
      - server
    volumes:
      - ~/.ssh:/root/.ssh
      - ./.git:/app/.git
      - web-modules:/app/node_modules
      - ./client/src:/app/src
      - ./client/public:/app/public
      # Mount the root folder that contains .git
      - .:/workspace:cached
volumes:
  api-modules:
  web-modules:
```

in `/server/devcontainer.json` you make something like this:

```
{
  "name": "Server Container",
  "dockerComposeFile": ["../docker-compose.yml"],
  "service": "server",
  "shutdownAction": "none",
  // Open the sub-folder with the source code
  "workspaceFolder": "/workspace/server"
}
```

in `/client/devcontainer.json` you make something like this:

```
{
  "name": "Client Container",
  "dockerComposeFile": ["../docker-compose.yml"],
  "service": "client",
  "shutdownAction": "none",
  // Open the sub-folder with the source code
  "workspaceFolder": "/workspace/client"
}
```

and to solve the many modified files I put this in my `.gitignore` file:

```
 * text=auto eol=lf
*.{cmd,[cC][mM][dD]} text eol=crlf
*.{bat,[bB][aA][tT]} text eol=crlf
```

and run
`git config --global core.autocrlf input` on the host computer (not inside the docker container) make sure you rebuild the container:

- (Ctrl+Shift+P on Windows/Linux, Cmd+Shift+P on macOS) and searching for `Dev Containers: Rebuild Without Cache and Reopen in Container`

here is a full explanation https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_resolving-git-line-ending-issues-in-wsl-resulting-in-many-modified-files